# Adding the resize function to an asp textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

In an   there is the function at the bottom right corner to drag and change the size of the box, is there a way of adding it to an asp textbox?

Textbox is as follows:

```
<div class="control">
<asp:TextBox  runat="server"  ID="TextBox1"  Width="100%"   EnableViewState="false" ViewStateMode="Disabled"    />
<asp:Label runat="server"  ID="Label1" Visible="false" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="false"  AssociatedControlID="TextBox1"  />
</div>
```

Comment: Resizable how? just the width of the textbox or the height too? Have you looked at textareas?

Comment: On the textarea html control it comes with the draggable function on the bottom right of the box, to drag and resize, but need it as an asp control preferably to a textbox. using a text area would be so much easier but needs to be an asp control

Comment: Why does it need to be an asp control?

Comment: As i am using many controls within the textbox already which arent in the html control, viewstatemode etc. is there not a way to add the resizable function to a textbox or is only text areas?

Comment: You can hack it up with jQuery `resize()` if Andy's answer isn't good enough for your needs but that looks very out of place. Code should be refactored if the functional need changes. If you need a textarea and a multiline textbox isn't good enough then the re-work might just have to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Set the attribute `TextMode="multiline"`, you can still set `Rows="1"` if you want it initially to look like a textbox/text input.

Comment: Thanks Andy, but does this add the resize tool to the bottom right corner of the text box?

Comment: Try it and see. That resize tool depends on the browser. (Setting Rows="2" may persuade it to appear.) I think 2 is preferable anyway, as the user is more likely to recognise that it could be resized.

Comment: I am using chrome but will try in IE, unfortunately it doesn't work even with rows=2

Comment: i got it to work using
                resize: both;
                overflow: auto; is there anyway to get this working in IE as it doesnt support resize

Comment: you guys are probably not using a native asp:textbox. with an asp:textbox, andy`s answer IS how you add multiline w/ scrollbar to the textbox. we're not talking about native html controls, this is for the asp:textbox which is very different from the native html one. thats why css doesnt work.